# Sorting an array in descending order 2 at a time in MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips, mips32

```
# read 10 numbers into an array
# swap any pairs of of number which are out of order
# then print the 10 numbers

# i in register $t0,
# registers $t1 - $t3 used to hold temporary results

main:

    li   $t0, 0         # i = 0
loop0:
    bge  $t0, 10, end0  # while (i < 10) {

    li   $v0, 5         #   scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    syscall             #

    mul  $t1, $t0, 4    #   calculate &numbers[i]
    la   $t2, numbers   #
    add  $t3, $t1, $t2  #
    sw   $v0, ($t3)     #   store entered number in array

    addi $t0, $t0, 1    #   i++;
    j    loop0          # 
end0:
    # PUT YOUR CODE HERE

    li   $t0, 1         # i = 1

loop1:
    bge  $t0, 10, end1  #   if (i >= 10) goto end1

    mul  $t1, $t0, 4    #   calculate &numbers[i]
    la   $t2, numbers   #
    add  $t3, $t1, $t2  #
    lw   $a0, ($t3)     #   load numbers[i] into $a0 (x)

    sub $t4, $t3, 4     
    lw  $a1, ($t4)      #load numbers[i - 1] into $a1 (y)

    bge $a0, $a1, increment #if (x >= y) goto increment

    add $t5, $a1, $zero       #store y in a temp variable
    add $a1, $a0, $zero       # numbers[i] = y
    add $a0, $t5, $zero       # numbers[i - 1] = x


increment:
    add  $t0, $t0, 1    #   i++
    j    loop1          

end1:
    li  $t0, 0          #i = 0

loop2:
    bge  $t0, 10, end2  #if (i >= 10) goto end2

    mul  $t1, $t0, 4    #   calculate &numbers[i]
    la   $t2, numbers #
    add  $t3, $t1, $t2  #
    lw   $a0, ($t3)     #   load numbers[i] into $a0 

    li   $v0, 1         #   printf("%d", numbers[i])
    syscall

    li   $a0, '\n'      #   printf("%c", '\n');
    li   $v0, 11
    syscall

    add  $t0, $t0, 1    #i++;
    j   loop2

end2:
    li   $v0, 0
    jr   $ra            # return 0

.data

numbers:
    .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  # int numbers[10] = {0};
```

This is the code I have written so far, and it only prints out the given array and does not reorder them. I have a feeling I am overwriting the swapping somewhere in loop2 but I am not sure where. How can I fix this to make it work in a simple way?

Functionality:
# reads 10 numbers into an array
# swap any pairs of of number which are out of order
# then print the 10 numbers

example

input: `12086, 24363, 47363, 64268, 34001, 6800, 60742, 48867, 26002, 54999`

output:
`12086, 24363, 47363, 34001, 6800, 60742, 48867, 26002, 54999, 64268`

An equivalent C program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int numbers[10] = { 0 };

    i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
        i++;
    }

    i = 1;
    while (i < 10) {
        int x = numbers[i];
        int y = numbers[i - 1];
        if (x < y) {
            numbers[i] = y;
            numbers[i - 1] = x;
        }
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging using single step?  If you don't know debugging, now is the time to learn.  Watch each line execute and verify its operation.  Check the program state (registers & memory) between each instruction.  Suggest working with fewer elements to sort in array (like 2 elements) to simplify debugging.

Comment: Focus on your swapping in loop1.

Comment: I tried printing out $a0 just after the swapping code and realised it wasn't working. I am a little lost on how to fix it though because I am not entirely sure what went wrong. Im new to assembler.

Comment: Can you see the `numbers` array in memory?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean sorry :(

Comment: You have a global variable (in `.data`) called `numbers`.  It is the array you are storing the values in, and the array you're trying to sort.  Can you see it in memory using the debugger?  If not, then work on using the debugger to (1) determine the address of the number array, and (2) view the memory for the array.  You should see values in the array.

Comment: You will need 2 nested loops instead of only one to perform sorting in this way.

Comment: When I run it on vscode I get no errors, the original array just prints. When using a debugger I get "Failed to parse input as an i32". I am a beginner so I'm not all that familiar with memory and debugging thats why I am struggling.

Comment: I can see the array in memory and frankly do not know what anything means, will look up videos on that, thank you @ErikEidt :(

Comment: You have made 1 'pass' over the array, swapping adjacent pairs of numbers... You're not done yet... You need to repeat the sweep across the array until there are no swaps performed...